# Showing $\overline{\{(v_n)_n \in \ell^{\infty}: (nv_n)_n \in \ell^{\infty}\}} = \{(v_n)_n \in l^{\infty}: v_n \rightarrow 0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $A = \{(v_n)_n \in \ell^{\infty} : (nv_n)_n \in \ell^{\infty}\}$ and suppose $c_0$ are the sequences that converge to $0$.

Then how does one show that $\bar{A} = c_o$.

First of all- if $(v_n)_n \in A$ that means $(nv_n)_n \in \ell^{\infty}$ which means there is some $C \geq 0$ such that $|nv_n| < C$ for all $n$ and so $|v_n| \leq C/n$ for all $n$ which would mean that $v_n \rightarrow 0$ after all. So $A \subseteq c_0$

I know that $c_0$ is closed (easy enough to see). And so $\bar{A} \subseteq c_0$.

How does one show that $c_0 \subseteq \bar{A}$?

I'm struggling to come up with a concrete sequence.

If $v_n \rightarrow 0$, then for every $m \geq 1$ I can find $N_m$ such that for all $n\geq N_m$ we have $|v_n| <1/m$. I considered defining $(u^m_n)_n$ such that $u_n = 1/nm$ for all $n \geq N_m$ and say $0$ for $n < N_m$. Then this would give us that $(u_n^m)_n \in A$ but it seems to shrink too fast to have that $u^m \rightarrow v$.

Would appreciate the help.

Comment: I suppose it would but I don't think $A$ is closed (and this would imply that $A = c_0 = \bar{A}$

Answer (score 0):

If $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\in c_0$, let, for each $k\in\Bbb N$, $(x_n^k)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be the sequence of real numbers defined by$$x_n^k=\begin{cases}x_n&\text{ if }n\leqslant k\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then each $(x_n^k)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ belongs to $A$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty}(x_n^k)_{n\in\Bbb N}=(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$.